# styling buttons via first-child and last-child and issues with dynamic insertions

Tags: css, angularjs

I have created a styled button in CSS that applies rounded corners to the first and last elements.

It looks like this:

[image]

Now the problem is that depending on specific conditions, I need to insert new buttons using angular `ng-if`. When I do that, the new buttons mess up the first and last child rounded corners. For example, here is the same image above with the new buttons added when certain conditions are met:

[image]

Note that in the above image adding the X and pin icon with an `ng-if` causes rounding issues.

How do I change the code so that if dynamic buttons are added or removed, the rounded first and last child don't get messed up? **I'd prefer NOT to create two different lists** based on `ng-if`. I'd rather keep on list with elements `ng-if`'d

The reference HTML code:

```
<div id="flyoutmenu" style="float:left">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" ng-click="sliderChanged(1)"> <i class="ion-plus-circled"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" ng-click="sliderChanged(-1)"> <i class="ion-minus-circled"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <span ng-if="isDragabillyOn">
                        <li>
                            <a href="" ng-click="hideMonitor(monitor.Monitor.Id)"> <i class="ion-close-circled"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" ng-click="toggleStamp()"> <i class="ion-pin"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </span>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#flyoutmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#flyoutmenu ul li a i {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#flyoutmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .2em;
    padding: 0.7em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

#flyoutmenu li:first-child {
    /*background: rgba(192, 57, 43, 0.7);*/
    background: rgba(108, 122, 137, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#flyoutmenu li:only-child {
    /*background: rgba(192, 57, 43, 0.7);*/
    background: rgba(108, 122, 137, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#flyoutmenu li:last-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}


/* make sure this is after last-child */

#flyoutmenu li:only-child {

    background: rgba(108, 122, 137, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#flyoutmenu li:nth-child(n+2) {
    background: rgba(108, 122, 137, 0.7);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: You can not expect proper results when you write faulty HTML. `span` can not be a child of `ul`. You _created_ this "problem" yourself with that code - your element with the X in it _is_ a first child, so the browser has no other choice than to style it this way, because that is what you told it to do.

Comment: Fair enough, chalk to up to my inexperience. What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the span so all list-items have the same parent. Then add `ng-if`'s to the list-items themselves.

```
                    <li ng-if="isDragabillyOn">
                        <a href="" ng-click="hideMonitor(monitor.Monitor.Id)"> <i class="ion-close-circled"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-if="isDragabillyOn">
                        <a href="" ng-click="toggleStamp()"> <i class="ion-pin"></i></a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: I could swear I tried this first and it resulted in tiny blank button backgrounds when they were supposed to be hidden - but it works now! I must have done something wrong then. Thanks!